# Extracting array items with ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given this array

```
[
 {"name": "bob",  "age": 25, "married": "Y"},
 {"name": "jane", "age": 31, "married": "N"},
 {"name": "sarah","age": 22, "married": "Y"}
]
```

what is the most succinct way to extract an array of married people, using ES6 (presumably with an arrow function)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Array.prototype.filter`.

Comment: Also, your JSON is invalid, there should be a colon after "married", not a comma.

Comment: @wateriswet it's not JSON, those are array and object literals (but they are not syntactically correct indeed)

Comment: @zerkms are you trolling?

Comment: @wateriswet not at all. You're using the terminology wrong, it's not JSON (by definition).

Comment: @zerkms I have no idea what you're talking about, this is definitely JSON (by definition).

Comment: JSON is a serialized string version of a Javascript data structure, presumably the data here is an example of an in-memory data structure, thus it is not JSON.

Comment: @wateriswet well, then you need to reconsider your definition based on the JS and JSON specifications.

Comment: @loganfsmyth tell http://jsonlint.com/ to change their name then, because they definitely consider this valid JSON.

Comment: `"bar"` is also a valid json, but in a `var foo = "bar";` statement you would not call it JSON, but a *string*.

Comment: @wateriswet JSON is *always* a string. The above is not a string. It is an array literal, therefore it is not JSON.

Comment: @naomik That makes sense, but according to whom, under what set of standards is JSON defined as specifically a string?

Comment: It is defined as so by the JSON specification.

Comment: @wateriswet another reinforcement of this idea is `JSON.parse` accepts a string only. `JSON.parse("[1,2,3]") //=> [1,2,3]` works but `JSON.parse([1,2,3]) //=> Error`; If you can't `JSON.parse` it, it's not JSON.

Comment: @zerkms where can I find that JSON.com doesn't say it has to be a string.

Comment: @wateriswet the whole standard is about serialising limited set of data types into a character-based stream. It does not state "it should be a string" explicitly since not every programming language denotes such a datatype. If you still think it's JSON - check the JS standard first. You're writing JS, so everything you type complies with the JS standard. Then find that JS standard does not define JSON in any way. Which means - there is no such a thing as "JSON" that you can see in the JS listing.

Comment: @zerkms I think I get it now, because OP used this literally in his JS it's not JSON. Thanks for taking the time to explain it.

Comment: @wateriswet yep, just to summarise: the JSON standard just specifies the format, not the medium that will carry it. In case of JS the only medium that is capable of holding JSON is a `string` data type.

Comment: @zerkms That actually makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Comment: @naomik Thank you as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a filter!

```
array.filter( obj => obj.married=="Y" );
```